# Performance of queries in Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

We are currently using Envers in a project and performance degrades a lot as we query some audited data that is spread around multiple tables.

Basically we create a stream of audited data as follows:

```
List<Object[]> auditStream = new LinkedList<Object[]>();
for (Class<?> entityClass : desiredEntityClasses) {
    auditStream.addAll(
        auditReader.createQuery()
            .forRevisionsOfEntity(entityClass, false, true)
            .add(AuditEntity
                .revisionProperty("timestamp")
                .ge(startTimestamp))
            .getResultList());    
}
```

On top of that some extra audit information is needed for some kinds of entities (like nested entities).

The response times are reasonable for small amounts of data (by reducing the timestamp) but with 500 entries in the `auditStream`, it takes about 3s to get it all, which is way too long.

**Q1** I was wondering if it was possible to turn on batch-fetching on those kind of queries and how?

**Q2** Is there some way to optimize the queries, for instance getting more than one kind of entity at once?

Answer (score 2):

One Audition is a collection of changes in multiple Tables!

If you use a Revision-Table (REVINFO) referenced by the REVID all the other Tables will get inspected for matching changes for this REVID.

Q1: Not all Changes of depending Tables depends on your Entity-Audition, Batch-Fetch cant work here.

Q2: You better fetch changes directly via HQL or plain SQL.

Comment: thanks, for your answer. It seems however that envers does not support HQL. Can you also explain more about your statement: [If you use a Revision-Table (REVINFO) referenced by the REVID all the other Tables will get inspected for matching changes for this REVID]

Comment: Hibernate is "Transactionable", so you change multiple tables in one transaction and commit those changes to the Database to a specific timestamp/timezone. To encapsul those changes you become a new column called "Revid" in your table-auditions with a foregin key to one entry in the REVINFO-Table who contains the execution-timestamp.

So every Transaction becomes one entry in the Table REVINFO.

Answer (score 1):

To implement this efficiently, you would need information about all the changes done in a revision in a single table - now you are querying multiple ones.

From the Envers side, maybe this would help:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-tracking-modified-entities-revchanges
This way you could get the names of the entities that changed at a revision, though I'm not sure what are your requirements for the stream - what you need to return to the end user.

Otherwise, I think you'd have to implement some custom modifications/store the necessary "stream" data in a separate entity.